# How do you lock the camera down in ZBrush?

Tags: zbrush

I'm trying to sculpt a tileable mesh on a flatplane and I keep inadvertently moving the camera when I go off canvas. Is there a way to lock the camera in place?

Comment: I don't think this is really gamedev related?

Comment: Zbrush is used in game development...

Comment: So is literally everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can save a camera angle using

Document>ZApplink properties> Then either choose front or Cust1

If you accidentally move your camera just navigate back to ZApplink properties and choose the camera you saved, it will snap the camera back to the saved position.